# could anyone please help me find what exactly the error is?

Tags: php, mysql

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on string in C:\wamp\www\websits\admin\validate.php on line 17
> ( ! ) Error: Call to a member function prepare() on string in C:\wamp\www\websits\admin\validate.php on line 17

Code-

```
<?php
include_once('connection.php');

function test_input($data) {
  
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]== "POST") {
  
  $adminname = test_input($_POST["adminname"]);
  $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM adminlogin");
  $stmt->execute();
  $users = $stmt->fetchAll();
  
  foreach($users as $user) {
    
    if(($user['adminname'] == $adminname) && 
      ($user['password'] == $password)) {
        header("Location: adminpage.php");
    }
    else {
      echo "<script language='javascript'>";
      echo "alert('WRONG INFORMATION')";
      echo "</script>";
      die();
    }
  }
}
?>

// Connection -
<?php
$conn= "";

try {
  $servername = "localhost:3306";
  $dbname = "website";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";

  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername and  dbname=website",$username, $password);
  
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,
  PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Get rid of that awful `test_input` function. Not only doesn't it "test" anything, it doesn't even properly do what it purports to be doing. Read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Answer (score 1):

Check Your connection.php file is it in the same directory where validate.php file is if not them provide the correct path, else your prepare statement is correct.

Where is you Connection file is can you share the path of of connection.php and validate.php path.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "your_db_name";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string is wrong

```
Your string
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername and  dbname=website",$username, $password);
```

Should be

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$servername};dbname={$dbname}",$username, $password);
```

And your servername should be without a port
$servername = "localhost";

Please see
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Answer (score 0):

Alter your connection.php code as follows,

```
  $username = 'root';
  $password = '';
  $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=website',$db_username,$db_password );
  if(!$conn){
    die("Fatal Error: Connection Failed!");
  }
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\wamp\www\websits\admin\connection.php:4 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\websits\admin\connection.php(4): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '') #1 C:\wamp\www\websits\admin\validate.php(3): include_once('C:\\wamp\\www\\web...') #2 {main} Next PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\wamp\www\websits\admin\connection.php on line 4